# How to query databases to get user roles?

Tags: sql-server, roles, ssms

I have been assigned a task in which I have no knowledge or experience. I am working on a .NET solution where I need to use SQL to query an instance of a database in sql. For each database in the instance, I need to retrieve a list of users and what role they belong to. Thank you in advance!

I have found this script below, but it requires admin rights.

Is there a way to do this without admin rights?

```
DECLARE @DB_USers TABLE (
    DBName SYSNAME
    ,UserName SYSNAME
    ,AssociatedRole VARCHAR(max)
    )

INSERT @DB_USers
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'use [?]
SELECT '' ? '' AS DB_Name
    ,CASE prin.NAME
        WHEN '' dbo ''
            THEN prin.NAME + '' (
                    '' + (
                        SELECT SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid)
                        FROM master.sys.databases
                        WHERE NAME = '' ? ''
                        ) + ''
                    ) ''
        ELSE prin.NAME
        END AS UserName
    ,isnull(USER_NAME(mem.role_principal_id), '''') AS AssociatedRole
FROM sys.database_principals prin
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_role_members mem ON prin.principal_id = mem.member_principal_id
WHERE prin.sid IS NOT NULL
    AND prin.sid NOT IN (0x00)
    AND prin.is_fixed_role <> 1
    AND prin.NAME NOT LIKE '' ## %'''

SELECT dbname
    ,username
    ,STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(500), associatedrole)
            FROM @DB_USers user2
            WHERE user1.DBName = user2.DBName
                AND user1.UserName = user2.UserName
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS Permissions_user
FROM @DB_USers user1
GROUP BY dbname
    ,username
ORDER BY DBName
    ,username
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.  It lists each user and their role.

```
SELECT users.name, roles.name
FROM sys.database_role_members roleToUsers JOIN sys.database_principals roles
        ON roleToUsers.role_principal_id = roles.principal_id
JOIN sys.database_principals users
    ON roleToUsers.member_principal_id = users.principal_id;
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Does this work foreach server in an instance or as a standalone?